# What's the appropriate class design for exporting testable functions in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a couple of stateless classes that do some business logic and return some computations. Each one of them has naturally a set of dependencies on other classes.

Now there are two designs that I've juggling between:

1. Have a class where each method is a static method. I can use jest import mocking, to overwrite the dependencies for testing. Advantage is you only have one class instance.
2. Have a class with regular non-static methods. This would require instantiating the class in each place it is used. I can pass in class dependencies in the constructor. Testing this is pretty straightforward. Drawback is you create multiple class instances and potentially dependencies in the code.

Which of these is the preferred idiomatic TS approach?

There is also the classic solution of using an IoC container, but I'd like to avoid this since this application is fairly small and don't want to add extra bloat.

Also, don't want to export pure functions and forego classes all together since that means I'll lose auto-importing of classes (in VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

> Also, don't want to export pure functions and forego classes all together since that means I'll lose auto-importing of classes (in VSCode).

Can you explain what is this "auto-importing of classes (in VSCode)"? In VSCode, I'm using extensions like [TypeScript Importer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pmneo.tsimporter) that adds the appropriate imports for any type (`class`, `function`, `literal`...), not only for classes.

Anyway, IMO, it's the "pure functions" approach that is the more JavaScript idiomatic, at least for those (including me) who likes the JavaScript functional programming features. It's true for TypeScript too, even with its sympathy for classes and C#/Java-like object oriented programming.

If you really prefer classes, avoid static i.e. option #1. You can instanciate and share instances while bootstrapping your application (like a DI container would do) to avoid multi instances.

Coupling between classes is less an issue in TypeScript due to its structural typings: a class can act as an interface → if class A depends on class B, you can always provide a class B-like object to the class A instance.